# How can i use escape to close a preview window which will ask user to enter his name

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping, keypress, keydown

The issue is I have a link `Onclick` of that user will get a pop-up displaying some image and a text area saying enter your name .

something like what FaceBook provides, for example see this **[Demo.](http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=283876108338751&set=a.251472534912442.59950.251047451621617&type=1&theater)**

**I want this functionality.**

If user has entered some thing inside that text he should not be able to close that pop preview using escape.

If he has not entered anything or he is not focusing on that text area then he should be able to close that pop-up preview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code in the pop-up `window`.

```
       $(document).bind("keyup", function (e) {
            if (!$('textarea').val() && e.keyCode === 27) {
                window.close();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks !! We can add jQuery('textarea').focused to check also whether he is focused or not . to close that pop-up.